# How to have field type support for date in kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

using debezium-mongodb-connector i managed to push my collections to kafka, the only problem i'm facing is that the field `date` in one of my collections with this format 2019-05-14T23:25:34.703+00:00, is not being pushed to the topic with the same format but rather i get something like this 1560708085175.

this is my debezium connector command `connect-standalone /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /etc/kafka/connect-mongodb-source.properties`

this is my mongodb collection example.

```
{"_id":"5cdb4e6ed767ba70593e2aa8","sender":"5cdb43db4505956efc70ba03","receiver":"5cdb43db4505956efc70ba03","receiverWalletId":"5cdb43db4505956efc70ba04","status":"succes","type":"topup","amount":200000,"totalFee":0,"createdAt":"2019-05-14T23:25:34.703Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-14T23:25:35.132Z","__v":0,"details":"none."}
```

and this is my kafka topic example.

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"sender"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"receiver"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"receiverWalletId"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"status"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"type"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"amount"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"totalFee"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"createdAt"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"updatedAt"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"__v"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"from"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"orderId"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"id"}],"optional":false,"name":"mongo_conn.digi.transactions"},"payload":{"sender":"5cef970ca2e9c273c655483","receiver":"5cef970ca2e9c27355c483","receiverWalletId":"5cef970ca2e9c27556c484","status":"pending","type":"topup","amount":6000,"totalFee":0,"createdAt":1560708024322,"updatedAt":1560708024753,"__v":0,"from":"smt","orderId":"d7a97581-9d18-79cd-8b09-16e400a43714","id":"5d0683b8be4af834abe3cf58"}}
```

and this is my connect-mongodb-source.properties

```
name=mongodb-source-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
mongodb.hosts=repracli/**.**.**.***27017
mongodb.name=mongo_conn
initial.sync.max.threads=1
tasks.max=1
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongo$
transforms.unwrap.operation.header=true
```

Answer (score 1):

For several transformations you will need something like:

```js
transforms=unwrap,convert1,convert2
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope
transforms.unwrap.operation.header=true
transforms.convert1.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert1.target.type=string
transforms.convert1.field=createdAt
transforms.convert1.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
transforms.convert2.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert2.target.type=string
transforms.convert2.field= *updatedAt*
transforms.convert2.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Debezium streams the data in format as they are stored in oplog. The date looks like unix timestamp in milliseconds since epoch.

You can write a SMT (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-66%3A+Single+Message+Transforms+for+Kafka+Connect) that will manipulate the message and convert the requested fields into your preferred string representation.

If you look into `org.bson.BsonDateTime` you'll see that it is really `long` value.

Comment: i've added these line to my connect-mongodb-source.properties.

"transforms": "TimestampConverter",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.field":"createdAt"
"transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
"transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "string"

it's not working though

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
name=mongodb-source-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
mongodb.hosts=repracli/**.**.**.***:27017
mongodb.name=mongo_conn
initial.sync.max.threads=1
tasks.max=1
transforms=unwrap,convert,convert2,convert3,convert4
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope
transforms.unwrap.operation.header=true
transforms.convert.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert.target.type=string
transforms.convert.field=createdAt
transforms.convert.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
transforms.convert2.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert2.target.type=string
transforms.convert2.field=updatedAt
transforms.convert2.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
transforms.convert3.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert3.target.type=string
transforms.convert3.field=created_at
transforms.convert3.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
transforms.convert4.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert4.target.type=string
transforms.convert4.field=updated_at
transforms.convert4.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
```